# Unable to convert string to timestamp on postgresql with sqlalchemy. I have tried all possible ways but nothing seems to work

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am working on a Flask project with Postgresql as my database. I have a schema called interest which looks like

```
create table interest(
usr int,
activity_category int,
activity_subcategory int, 
pid int,
start_time timestamp,
end_time timestamp,
budget int check (budget >= 0),
primary key (usr, activity_category, activity_subcategory, pid, start_time, end_time),
foreign key (usr) references users(userid),
foreign key(pid, activity_category, activity_subcategory) references location(pid, aid, aaid)
```

);

I am trying to insert values into the interest table. At present, I have starttime and endtime as strings but I guess I need to somehow typecast them to timestamp. I have tried these two methods but none of them work.

```
entry_by_location = g.conn.execute("insert into interest(usr, activity_category, activity_subcategory, pid, start_time, end_time, budget) values (%d, %d, %d, %d, to_timestamp(%s::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI'), to_timestamp(%s::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI'), %d)" %(int(uid), int(aaid), int(aid), int(pid), starttime, endtime, budget))
```

and

```
entry_by_location = g.conn.execute("insert into interest(usr, activity_category, activity_subcategory, pid, start_time, end_time, budget) values (%d, %d, %d, %d, %s::timestamp, %s::timestamp, %d)" %(int(uid), int(aaid), int(aid), int(pid), starttime, endtime, budget))
```

The error that I get is -

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "10"
LINE 1: ... end_time, budget) values (1, 2, 7, 1, 2016-11-15 10:13::tim...
                                                             ^
 [SQL: 'insert into interest(usr, activity_category, activity_subcategory, pid, start_time, end_time, budget) values (1, 2, 7, 1, 2016-11-15 10:13::timestamp, 2016-10-15 11:24::timestamp, 1000)']

I've spent two days trying to figure this out. Any sort of help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Trying adding quotes like `'%s'`

Comment: That worked! Wow. This is interesting. I need to put quotes with %s so that a date with a string data type gets converted to '2014-20-10' instead of simply being 2014-20-10.

Comment: Thank a lot @viki888

Comment: I will post this solution as an answer and kindly make it as the best answer, so that it would be helpful for others

Comment: Sounds good! Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message it is clear that, there is an error near **10**. That is the sql cannot recognise the datatype of **2016-11-15 10:13** due to space exist between Date and Time.

So adding quotes to `%s` will solve the issue like `'%s'`.